# filtering query result

Tags: php, mysql

I use a query something like this to get tutors and institutes.

```
SELECT 
  t.tutor_id member_id,
  t.tutor_name member_name,
  t.tutor_code member_code,
  'tutor' AS TYPE 
FROM
  tutors t 
WHERE t.tutor_name LIKE '%jaya%' 
UNION
SELECT 
  t.institute_id,
  t.institute_name,
  t.institute_code,
  'institute' AS TYPE 
FROM
  institute i 
WHERE i.institute_name LIKE '%jaya%'
```

This query is returning both records (tutors and institutes) according to given keyword. Its working for me. My problem is I need to keep record separately as tutors and institutes afters selecting all records from the query. I have use 2 buttons named 'tutors' and 'institute' on my page to filter query result. So now I need to know do I need to use 2 different queries for each button or if not can I use single query for do this?

Any comments are greatly appreciating. 
Thank you.

Comment: Easier and more efficient to use separate queries

Comment: share the table schema for both `tutors` and `institute` tables.

Comment: can you tell me how I share the table schema?

Comment: Why would you be referring to `tutors` table after `UNION`?

Comment: BTW, @TharangaNuwan Table schema can be generated using `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>`

Comment: Is your i.Institute.name  and t.tutor_name is same or it is just example you are using to match jaya?

Comment: not same. They are different and selecting all records that match with keyword.

Answer (score 0):

When a button let suppose tutors is clicked send two parametes to php function

```
function searchTutors($type , $keyword)
{
    if($type == 'tutors')
    {
        //tutors query here
    }else{
        //institutions query here
    }
    return $your_query_result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to run a single query only, you can have separate views.

```
$type=$_POST['submit'];

if($type=='tutor')
{
  // show only columns from tutor table
}
else
{
 // show only columns from institute table
}
```